# How to avoid the order of execution of these methods? (Angular)

Tags: angular

The objective I want to achieve is that the items that I keep in a Cart are reviewed to check the availability that I have of them in Stock.

**How do I get this review?**

With a for loop I go through these items and I can get the IDs of the products and the quantities I want of each one of them. Then, I proceed to call a method in the service to reduce the stock as I go through this route. Finally, I call another method of the service that does is recover that lost stock.

I attach the two methods that I have in the service:

```
productStock(id: number, quantity: number): Observable<any> {
    try {
      return this.http.put<any>(`${this.productsUrl}/productStock/${id}/${quantity}`, Boolean);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error.message);
    }
  }

retrieveProductStock(id: number, quantity: number): Observable<any> {
    try {
      return this.http.put<any>(`${this.productsUrl}/retrieveStock/${id}/${quantity}`, Boolean);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error.message);
    }
  }
```

Next I will leave you the methods that I have applied:

```
for (let i = 0; i < productsItem.length; i++) {
      let id = productsItem[i].product.id;
      let quantity = productsItem[i].quantity;
      console.log("ID: " + id);
      console.log("Quantity: " + quantity);
      this.productService.productStock(Number(id), quantity).subscribe(res => {
        console.log("Executing method '1'");
      })
   }
   console.log("Cycle finished");
```

This method works the way I want it to, since it correctly reduces my stock. The problem is when I want to join it with another method that consists of recovering the stock that was lost with the first one.

Here is the second method:

```
console.log("Recovering the stock of the products");

for (let i = 0; i < productsItem.length; i++) {
  let id = productsItem[i].product.id;
  let quantity = productsItem[i].quantity;
  console.log("ID: " + id);
  console.log("Quantity: " + quantity);
  this.productService.retrieveProductStock(Number(id), quantity).subscribe(res => {
    console.log("Executing method '2'");
  })
}
console.log("Cycle finished");
```

- Testing this method individually works like i want, that is, without the presence of the first method.

I charge a single item to the Cart and attach the amount of '2', then I proceed to execute the 2 methods developed above and I get this result:

- ID: 1
- Quantity: 2
- Recovering the stock of the products
- ID: 1
- Quantity: 2
- Cycle finished
- Executing method '1'
- Executing method '2'

The order that I THINK it should be is the following:

- ID: 1
- Quantity: 2
- Executing method '1' (discounts the stock)
- Cycle finished
- Recovering the stock of the products
- ID: 1
- Quantity: 2
- Executing method '1' (recovers the stock)
- Cycle finished

I already appreciate any kind of help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do is transform your subscribe to a promise:

```js
await this.productService.retrieveProductStock(Number(id), quantity).toPromise()
console.log("Executing method '2'");
```

Now your code will wait the product be retrieved and show the console log after it